# how to unit test httpParams in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm pretty new in unit testing. I have a function which is setting query params:

```
setParams(scale): HttpParams {
    return this.params = new HttpParams()
        .set('scale', scale);
}
```

The output is passing right to the http get method. But I have no idea how to test if the function above is really giving http params. Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
it('should set params', () => {
  const params = service.setParams('hello'); // I assume this is in the service code
  expect(params.get('scale')).toBe('hello');
});
```